# Next.js 13 - Why isn't my root page dynamic

Tags: typescript, next.js

I am making a website with Next.js 13.0. When I run next build, all the pages work except my root page. It's being built as static when I want it to be dynamic. I even have `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"` in my code yet it continues to build as a static page. It's no different from my dynamic pages so I don't get what's the problem.

The code for src/app/page.tsx:

```
import { collection, getDocs, limit, orderBy, query } from "firebase/firestore"
import Article from "@components/Article"
import { ArticleData } from "@types"
import { db } from "@firebase"

export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"

const getArticles = async () => {
  const articles: ArticleData[] = []

  const snapshot = await getDocs(
    query(collection(db, "articles"), orderBy("created", "desc"), limit(5))
  )

  snapshot.forEach((doc) => {
    articles.push({
      ...doc.data(),
      id: doc.id,
    } as ArticleData)
  })

  return articles
}

const Home = async () => {
  const articles = await getArticles()

  return (
    <>
      {articles.map((data, i) => (
        <Article key={i} data={data} />
      ))}
    </>
  )
}

export default Home
```

Any ideas?

Comment: How do you know the `<Article/>` elements are static? When you view the page source are they present as though returned from getStaticProps?

Comment: @bknights When I run next build and it outputs the First Load JS, it tells me that the "/" route is static.

Comment: and what happens when you run your built script, add an article and refresh the home page?

Comment: @bknights The new article doesn't show up. It only shows the articles from before the build because they are cached on the server.

Answer (score 3):

Replace this `export const dynamic = "force-dynamic"` by this code `export const revalidate = 0`

My source https://supabase.com/blog/fetching-and-caching-supabase-data-in-next-js-server-components

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and found a solution.

If you add the Dynamic functions like cookies() and headers() to a server side page you will force the page to be dynamic.

Example

```
import { headers } from 'next/headers';

export default async function page() {
    const headersList = headers();
    
    //...
    
}
```

I found this solution in the [next.js docs](https://beta.nextjs.org/docs/data-fetching/fetching#default-caching-behavior) under the heading **Default Caching Behavior**

Hope this helps